# sudo apt-get not working after a new install of ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I installed ubuntu last night. And after reading 100s of posts, I still couldn't make my `sudo apt-get` work at all. I remember, I have to modify the software server somehow. But I can't remember how or where to do it.

Nothing is being installed.

Need help.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: @Mitch: `sudo apt-get install git`

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before installing, and then try to install git.  let me know what happens.

Comment: Show us some console output of the error message, to help figure out what is not working.

Comment: @Mitch: It's still installing the packages. I'll notify you when things get done.

Comment: @xan Then you should answer how did you solve it.

Comment: @Radu: Answered it. Done.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a fresh install of Ubuntu, launch Terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once, this process has been completed, you can install packages using

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should clear your existing lists and rebuild.